# MAX30102 doesnt show data when it's interfacing with other sensors MLX90614 and MPU6050

Tags: arduino-ide, sensors, esp32, blynk

The hardware I am using is ESP32 with MAX30102, MLX90614 and MPU6050 sensors and Using Blynk to show my data from the sensors. The issue I am facing is when I ran the code with all three sensors only the MAX30102 sensor doesn't show data.

I tried troubleshooting with only two sensors at a time and when the MAX30102 sensor is involve I only can get the other sensors data.
I tried troubleshooting with only the MAX30102 sensor only and it works I don't understand what is going on.

```
#include <WiFi.h>                   // include the Arduino WiFi library
#include <Wire.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <MAX30105.h>
#include <heartRate.h>
#include <Adafruit_MLX90614.h>
#include <Adafruit_MPU6050.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Blynk.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp32.h>

#define BLYNK_PRINT Serial

Adafruit_MLX90614 mlx = Adafruit_MLX90614(); //0x5A
MAX30105 particleSensor;

char auth[] = "0GUsnEJQJCDHF2HsLzYscYcDgXoe4KFg";  // Blynk code
const char *ssid = "Get your own Wifi";            // WiFi access name
const char *pass = "w1frjoyf00bar";                // WiFi password

const byte RATE_SIZE = 4; // Settings for Max 30102
byte rates[RATE_SIZE];
byte rateSpot = 0;
long lastBeat = 0;
float beatsPerMinute = 0;
float beatAvg = 0;

const int MPU_addr = 0x68; // I2C address of the MPU-6050
int16_t AcX, AcY, AcZ, Tmp, GyX, GyY, GyZ;
float ax = 0, ay = 0, az = 0, gx = 0, gy = 0, gz = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, pass);
  particleSensor.begin(Wire, I2C_SPEED_FAST);
  particleSensor.setup();
  particleSensor.setPulseAmplitudeRed(0x0A);   // Turn Red LED to low to indicate sensor is running
  mlx.begin();  // Start MLX sensor
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire.write(0x6B);  // PWR_MGMT_1 register
  Wire.write(0);     // set to zero (wakes up the MPU-6050)
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");              // print … till not connected
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
}

void mpu_read() {
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire.write(0x3B);  // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(MPU_addr, 14, true); // request a total of 14 registers
  AcX = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) & 0x3C (ACCEL_XOUT_L)
  AcY = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // 0x3D (ACCEL_YOUT_H) & 0x3E (ACCEL_YOUT_L)
  AcZ = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // 0x3F (ACCEL_ZOUT_H) & 0x40 (ACCEL_ZOUT_L)
  Tmp = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // 0x41 (TEMP_OUT_H) & 0x42 (TEMP_OUT_L)
  GyX = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // 0x43 (GYRO_XOUT_H) & 0x44 (GYRO_XOUT_L)
  GyY = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // 0x45 (GYRO_YOUT_H) & 0x46 (GYRO_YOUT_L)
  GyZ = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // 0x47 (GYRO_ZOUT_H) & 0x48 (GYRO_ZOUT_L)
}

void loop() {
  Blynk.run();
  
  long irValue = particleSensor.getIR();

   if (checkForBeat(irValue) == true)                    //If a heart beat is detected
  {        
    Serial.println("BPM");                        
    Serial.println(beatAvg); 
    Serial.println();
    delay(100);
    long delta = millis() - lastBeat;                   //Measure duration between two beats
    lastBeat = millis();
    beatsPerMinute = 60 / (delta / 1000.0);             //Calculating the BPM
    if (beatsPerMinute < 255 && beatsPerMinute > 20)    //To calculate the average we strore some values (4) then do some math to calculate the average
    {
      rates[rateSpot++] = (byte)beatsPerMinute;         //Store this reading in the array
      rateSpot %= RATE_SIZE;                            //Wrap variable
      beatAvg = 0;                                      //Take average of readings
      for (byte x = 0 ; x < RATE_SIZE ; x++)
        beatAvg += rates[x];
      beatAvg /= RATE_SIZE;
    }
//    Serial.println("");
//    Serial.println("BPM: ");
//    Serial.println(beatAvg);
  }

  delay(100);

  mpu_read();
  ax = (AcX + 1704) / 16384.00;
  ay = (AcY - 412) / 16384.00;
  az = (AcZ + 1765) / 16384.00;
  gx = (GyX + 82) / 131.07;
  gy = (GyY + 6) / 131.07;
  gz = (GyZ + 32) / 131.07;
  // calculating Amplitute vactor for 3 axis
  float Raw_Amp = pow(pow(ax, 2) + pow(ay, 2) + pow(az, 2), 0.5);
  int Amp = Raw_Amp * 10;  // Mulitiplied by 10 bcz values are between 0 to 1
  float roll = 57.2883514 * atan(ay / sqrt(ax * ax + az * az));

  Serial.print("\nAMP:");
  Serial.print(Amp);
  Serial.print("      ");
  Serial.print(", Roll:");
  Serial.println(roll);

  Serial.print("BPM = ");
  Serial.print(beatsPerMinute);
  Serial.print(", Avg BPM = ");
  Serial.print(beatAvg);
  Serial.println();

  Serial.print("Ambient Temp = ");
  Serial.print(mlx.readAmbientTempC());
  Serial.print("\n Object Temp = ");
  Serial.print(mlx.readObjectTempC());
  Serial.print("      ");

  Serial.print("      ");
  alertBPM();
  Serial.print("      ");
  alertTemp();

  Serial.print("\n-----------------------------------------------------------------");
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V1, beatAvg);
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V2, mlx.readObjectTempC());

}

void alertBPM() {                                 // Alert Trigger for Heart rate
  // BPM alert
  if (beatAvg >= 60 && beatAvg <= 110) {
    Serial.println("Heart rate normal");
  }

  if (beatAvg < 60 && beatAvg > 110) {
    Serial.println("Heart Rate Abnormal");        // Need to change the HR to hhr
    Blynk.logEvent("HR", "Heart Rate Abnormal");
  }
}

void alertTemp() {                                  // Alert Trigger for Body Temp
  // Body and ambient temp alert
  if (mlx.readObjectTempC() >= 35 && mlx.readObjectTempC() <= 39) {
    Serial.println("Body temp normal");
  }

  if (mlx.readObjectTempC() < 35 && mlx.readObjectTempC() > 39 ) {
    Serial.println("Body temp Abnormal");
    Blynk.logEvent("BT", "Body temp Abnormal");   // Need to change BT to hbt
  }
}
```

The output is this

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
AMP:11      , Roll:-2.12
BPM = 0.00, Avg BPM = 0.00
Ambient Temp = 30.75
 Object Temp = 36.07                  Body temp normal

-----------------------------------------------------------------
AMP:10      , Roll:3.90
BPM = 0.00, Avg BPM = 0.00
Ambient Temp = 30.77
 Object Temp = 36.07                  Body temp normal

-----------------------------------------------------------------
AMP:11      , Roll:-0.15
BPM = 0.00, Avg BPM = 0.00
Ambient Temp = 30.79
 Object Temp = 35.99                  Body temp normal

-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: what do you want to know? ... please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: if you want to know where to start debugging, then start by running an I2C scanner sketch

Comment: is Blynk somehow involved in the problem?

Comment: @Juraj blynk is not the issue in this.

Comment: try to create a minimal reproducible example

Comment: @Juraj what is a reproducible example

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example

Comment: @jsotola i used it and got this 

Scanning...
I2C device found at address 0x57
I2C device found at address 0x5A
I2C device found at address 0x68
done